# css how to align horizontal element inside <li>

Tags: css

I have this html code

```
<ul id="list-table">
    <li>
        <table id="test-tab">...</table>
        <ul id="panel-table">...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want table "test-tab" and ul "panel-table" inside li display horizontal like this http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v246/TuanVenus/table-css.png

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `float: left`. Normally, I'd go with `display: inline-block` but that might break the table layout. Don't forget to add a pseudo-element which provides the *clear-fix* for the parent element (`<li>`).

```css
#test-tab, #panel-table {
    float: left;
}
#list-table li::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give float to your elements like this:

**CSS**

```
.fleft { float:left;}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="test-tab" class="fleft">...</table>
<ul id="panel-table" class="fleft">...</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the same styles to your `CSS` as in http://jsfiddle.net/vMe5L/38/  Enjoy !!

Answer (score 0):

you could use display and wrap your table in a div, so it doesn't get broken:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tjesx/

```
#list-table {
  display:table;
  width:600px;
  border:solid;
  border-spacing:1em;
  padding:0;
}
#list-table > li {
  display:table-row;
}

#list-table > li > ul ,
#list-table > li > div
{
  display:table-cell;
  border:solid;
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<style>
#test-tab{
    float:left;
}

#panel-table{
    float:left;
}

</style>

<ul id="list-table">
    <li>
        <table id="test-tab"><tr><td>example table</td></tr></table>
        <ul id="panel-table"><li>example li</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add a css style

```
<ul id="list-table" style="list-style: none;">
```